# Index is not being used by optimizer

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing

I have a query which is performing very badly due to full scan of a table.I have checked the statistics rebuild  the indexes but its not working.

SQL Statement:

```
select distinct NA_DIR_EMAIL d, NA_DIR_EMAIL r
from gcr_items , gcr_deals
where gcr_deals.GCR_DEALS_ID=gcr_items.GCR_DEALS_ID 
and 
gcr_deals.bu_id=:P0_BU_ID
and 
decode(:P55_DIRECT,'ALL','Y',trim(upper(NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL)))=
decode(:P55_DIRECT,'ALL','Y',trim(upper(:P55_DIRECT))) 
order by 1

Execution Plan :
Plan hash value: 3180018891

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name             | Rows  | Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                  |     8 | 00:11:42 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY            |                  |     8 | 00:11:42 |
|   2 |   HASH UNIQUE             |                  |     8 | 00:11:42 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN              |                  |  7385 | 00:11:42 |
|*  4 |     VIEW                  | index$_join$_002 | 10462 | 00:00:05 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN            |                  |       |          |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN    | GCR_DEALS_IDX12  | 10462 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| GCR_DEALS_IDX1   | 10462 | 00:00:06 |
|*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL     | GCR_ITEMS        |  7386 | 00:11:37 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("GCR_DEALS"."GCR_DEALS_ID"="GCR_ITEMS"."GCR_DEALS_ID")
   4 - filter("GCR_DEALS"."BU_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:P0_BU_ID))
   5 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
   6 - access("GCR_DEALS"."BU_ID"=TO_NUMBER(:P0_BU_ID))
   8 - filter(DECODE(:P55_DIRECT,'ALL','Y',TRIM(UPPER("NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAI
              L")))=DECODE(:P55_DIRECT,'ALL','Y',TRIM(UPPER(:P55_DIRECT))))
```

Comment: Can you please post the execution plan and the indexes on your tables?

Comment: Without knowing what indexes are present on your tables and without seeing the execution plan it's impossible to guess what's going on. Please edit your question and include: A) the DDL for both tables, B) all indexes on both tables, C) the execution plan, and D) the number of rows in each table. Thanks.

Comment: `gcr_items` only contains 7386 rows - I doubt that an index access is really going to improve the performance as apparently you are selecting all rows from that table

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning a part of the condition in the WHERE clause must be decomposed (or "decompiled" - or "reengeenered") into a simpler form without using `decode` function, which a form can be understandable by the query optimizer:

```
AND
decode(:P55_DIRECT,'ALL','Y',trim(upper(NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL)))=
decode(:P55_DIRECT,'ALL','Y',trim(upper(:P55_DIRECT)))
```

into:

```
AND (
    :P55_DIRECT = 'ALL'
    OR
    trim(upper(:P55_DIRECT)) = trimm(upper(NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL))
)
```

To find rows in the table based on values stored in the index, Oracle uses an access method named ***Index scan***, see this link for details:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#i52300

One of the most common access method is **Index Range Scan** see here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#i45075

The documentation says (in the latter link) that:

> The optimizer uses a range scan when it finds one or more leading
>   columns of an index specified in conditions, such as the following:
>
> col1 = :b1
>
> col1 < :b1
>
> col1 > :b1
>
> AND combination of the preceding conditions for leading columns in the
>   index
>
> col1 like 'ASD%' wild-card searches should not be in a leading
>   position otherwise the condition col1 like '%ASD' does not result in a
>   range scan.

The above means that the optimizer is able to use the index to find rows only for query conditions that contain basic comparision operators: `= < > <= >= LIKE` which are used to **comparing simple values with plain column names**. 
What the documentation doesn't clearly say - and you need to deduce it reading between the lines - is a fact that when some function is used in the condition, in a form `function( column_name )` or `function( expression_involving_column_names )` , then **the index range scan cannot be used**. 
In this case the query optimizer must evaluate this expression individually for each row in the table, thus must read all rows (perform a full table scan).

---

A short conclusion and a rule of thumb:

> **Functions in the WHERE clause can prevent the optimizer from using
>   indexes**
>
> If you see some function somewhere in the WHERE clause, then it is a sign that you are
>   running the red light
>   **STOP immediately** and think three times how
>   this function impact the query optimizer and the performance of your
>   query, and try to rewrite the condition to a form that the optimizer
>   is able to understand.

---

Now take a look at our rewritten condition:

```
AND (
    :P55_DIRECT = 'ALL'
    OR
    trim(upper(:P55_DIRECT)) = trimm(upper(NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL))
)
```

and **STOP** - there are still two functions `trim`  and `upper` applied to a column named NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL. We need to think how they can impact the query optimizer.

I assume that you have created a plain index on a single column:
 `CREATE INDEX somename ON GCR_ITEMS( NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL )`.
If yes, then the index contains only plain values of NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL.
But the query is trying to find `trimm(upper(NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL))` values, which are not stored in the index, so this index cannot be used in this case.
This condition requires a **function based index**:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505

`CREATE INDEX somename ON GCR_ITEMS( trim( upper( NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL )))`

---

Unfortunately even the function based index will still not help, because the condition in the query is too general - if a value of :P55_DIRECT = ALL the query must retrieve all rows from the table (perform a full table scan), otherwise must use the index to search value within it.

This is because the query is planned (think of it as "compiled") by the query optimizer only once, during it's first execution. Then the plan is stored in the cache and used to execute the query for all further executions. A value of the parameter is not know in advance, so the plan must consider each possible cases, thus will always perform a full table scan.
In 12c there is a new feature "Adaptive query optimalization":
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optcncpt.htm#TGSQL94982

where the query optimizer analyses each parameters of the query on each runs, and is able to detect that the plan is not optimal for some runtime parameters, and choose a better "subplans" depending on actual parameter's value ... but you must use 12c, and additionally pay for Enterprise Edition, because only this edition includes that feature. And it's still not certain if the adaptive plan will work in this case or not.
What you can do without paying for 12c EE is to DIVIDE this general query into two separate variants, one for a case where :P55_DIRECT = ALL, and the other for remaining cases, and run an appropriate variant in the client (your application) depending on the value of this parameter.
A version for :P55_DIRECT = ALL, that will perform a full table scan

```
where gcr_deals.GCR_DEALS_ID=gcr_items.GCR_DEALS_ID 
and 
gcr_deals.bu_id=:P0_BU_ID
order by 1
```

and a version for other cases, that will use the function based index:

```
where gcr_deals.GCR_DEALS_ID=gcr_items.GCR_DEALS_ID 
and 
gcr_deals.bu_id=:P0_BU_ID
and 
 trim(upper(:P55_DIRECT)) = trimm(upper(NA_ORG_OWNER_EMAIL))
order by 1
```